# Send packets to neighboring nodes and use multi-hop routing in Castalia Simulator

Tags: omnet++

I want to simulate a `WBAN` routing protocol in **Castalia** simulator.

First of all, I want nodes to send broadcast messages to all of their neighbors. In Castalia, as a default manner nodes send Broadcast messages not only to neighbors but also to all nodes in the network. as a result, we don't have any relay node to forward packets.

> So, I think that Castalia uses single-hop routing and therefore
>   multi-hop routing is not defined in it.

*How can I implement multi-hop routing in Castalia?*

Comment: I am not sure what purpose the quote from Wikipedia serves in this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In Castalia, as a default manner nodes send Broadcast messages not only to neighbors but also to all nodes in the network. as a result, we don't have any relay node to forward packets.
>   [...] So, I think that Castalia uses single-hop routing and therefore multi-hop routing is not defined in it.

I am note sure where you are getting this information, but this is wrong. Castalia is capable of multihop  routing, there is even a Routing module called MultipathRingsRouting in the default distribution.

Moreover, your statements seem to be contradictory with each other. How can Castalia send messages to all nodes in the network (not just single-hop neighbours) and yet not support any multihop routing? Can you see how these are contradictory statements? In the same spirit how can Castalia send messages to all nodes in the network and "as a result, we don't have any relay node to forward packets". Can you see how this does not make much sense.

Perhaps you are confused by the BAN simulation examples in Castalia which define networks where **all the nodes are a single hop from the BAN hub**. This does not mean that Castalia in general cannot support multihop routing. It does.

You mention a WBAN Routing protocol in your question. You should note that the current implementation of the BaselineBANMAC in Castalia does not support multi-hop communication. Just to be clear, I am talking about this specific MAC and not Castalia as a whole. This MAC does not support any routing on top of it because it only allows communication between the hub and the slave nodes. There can only be one hub per network. You can have multiple networks (each having a hub) in your simulation, but these will be logically seperate and can only interfere with each other, not communicate. Perhaps, you wanted to use this MAC in your simulations. You will not be able to explore routing with this MAC.

You can however use other MACs (such as TunableMAC, or TMAC) that allow routing to be used on top of them. To be clear, the MAC does not do any routing, this is done by the routing layer above it (a separate module), but a MAC design can allow a routing layer to operate above it, or not. Make sure you read the manual carefully and have a solid understanding of the basics.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Maybe I confused by the BAN simulation scenario. But I did't use baseline mac for my simulation example.
I used **StaticGTS802154** by below code:

```SN.node[*].Communication.MACProtocolName = "StaticGTS802154"```



I want to work only on routing layer for multi-hop communications without focusing on the MAC layer. So, which MAC protocol is suitable for wban scenarios with a multi-hop routing protocol?

Comment: StaticGTS802154 is also a hub-based MAC and like BaselineBANMAC does not support multi-hop communication (so no routing). In my answer I gave a couple of examples of MACs you could use. If you found my answer useful you can upvote it,  and you can also accept it.

Comment: Now, I've used other Mac protocols with the MBR routing protocol at the same time. But in the example of the BAN network in the Castalia simulator that uses 6 nodes, we have at most two levels, which does not differ from the baseline. But when I increase the number of nodes to 100, the number of levels reaches 3. But I want to have more levels to show the routing algorithm's effect. What should I do?

Comment: This is a different question, and unrelated to the answer above. If you have separate questions you should ask them separately (start a new question). If this answer or any other answer has answered the question as it appears here (not what you discovered in the process) you should upvote and accept it. Read stackoverflow's how-to to get hints about asking good questions.

Comment: Yes, that's right. But the problem is that, as I mentioned in the question, I plan to implement a routing protocol for the WBAN network in Catalia, and unfortunately in the example of BAN in Castalia, six nodes are used and there is practically no difference to a single-hop routing. In fact, my final question "_How can I implement multi-hop routing in Castalia?_" has not been answered.

Comment: Castalia already implements multi-hop routing. I pointed you to the right direction on how to find more about it, and it seems you used this info already. Good. You also seem to be having more questions about how MRR works and why it behaves a certain way. Study the available resources first, to understand as much as possible, and if you still have questions, ask them separately following this helpful guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask